What's wron with this SlickEdit macro?
What's wrong with this macro  It only performs the operation on the first line.

#include "slick.sh"

_command format_HTML() name_info(','VSARG2_MACRO|VSARG2_MARK|VSARG2_REQUIRES_MDI_EDITORCTL)
{
   _macro('R',1);

   top_of_buffer()
   while ( !down() ) {
        begin_line()
        last_event(name2event('<'));html_lt();
        keyin("p");
        last_event(name2event('>'));html_gt();
        last_event(name2event(' '));html_space();
        end_line();
        last_event(name2event(' '));html_space();
        last_event(name2event('<'));html_lt();
        keyin('/');
        keyin("p");
        last_event(name2event('>'));html_gt();
   }
}

This code is to format regular text into HTML paragraphs, however it only works on the first line.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
